# OS function calls from ActionScript 3 ExternalInterface

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, externalinterface

Using ExternalInterface in AS3 is it possible to call OS (C#?) functions within XP?

Example: Set the desktop background to a image supplied by a flash app?

If it is possible would it be different calls when applied to different OS. And what about cross over the Mac?

Any information would be great

Thanks

Comment: If you're planning on going cross platform C# might not be your best option.  I'd suggest you try Java or Python.

Answer (score 2):

If you're launching the swf from within a C# app, external interface will do just fine.  Nothing will change on the flash side, but you'll need to go through a couple hoops to get it to work in C#.  It's not as simple as AMF or External Interface to JS.

All the communications to C# get converted to XML describing the data, and you've gotta write XML to send back to flash.  Other than that though, its relativly simple.

[Here's some info](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/flashexternalapi.aspx) on how to do it.  The AS portion is Flash 8/AS2, but the C# portion should say the same.

Comment: I was just viewing that exact page :). thanks Alex.

In terms of communicating with Windows OS functions (set background for instance) will i need to create c# scripts to act as a bridge between a desktop base swf and the OS? or is it possible to interact direct with the OS?  Bare in mind i know nothing about the c# programing language - this is research into ideas.

Comment: Yup, you'd have to use C# (or some other programming language) as a go-between.  Flash doesn't have access to most of your computer for security reasons.  I'm sure there are ways to use EI with other languages too.  I did it once in Delphi years ago...C# more recently, and I'm sure you could do it in Java and whatnot as well.

Answer (score 1):

When working with Flash from a webpage or as a desktop app, you are limited to a small security sandbox and you will not be able to make any relevant OS call. I thought that switching to AIR would give the developper more flexibility but it doesn't seem correct either. From "[The Pros and Cons of Adobe Air](http://ajaxian.com/archives/the-pros-and-cons-of-adobe-air)":

> AIR apps have
>   file access, clipboard access, support
>   multiple windows, support drag and
>   drop, and can trigger notifications
>   (toast in Windows). If you app needs
>   to interact with the desktop in other
>   ways, the chances are that AIR is not
>   suitable. For example, there is no
>   access to COM automation, and no way
>   to execute external applications. The
>   reason is to maintain cross-platform
>   compatibility. That's a worthy goal,
>   but it would be good to have a way out
>   of the sandbox. Unlike Java or .NET,
>   you cannot extend AIR with custom
>   native code libraries. Nor can you
>   call operating system APIs.

As Alex Jillard commented, if your swf is called inside a C# desktop application, you should be able to access more OS funcionalities although I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

You could use as already mentioned [`AIR`](http://www.adobe.com/go/air). Another idea would be to use [`HippoHX`](http://hippohx.com/) (I haven't written this, the similarity with my username is just coincidence). It runs on top of the [`NekoVM`](http://nekovm.org) and gives you unrestricted (so no limitations like in `AIR` ) access to the system.